# Javascript -Check all Checkboxes form problem

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have some javascript code which orginally checked/unchecked multiple checkboxes which was great. But know I've HAD to move the checkboxes to another form...

I couldn't find a tutorial for checkboxes in another form anywhere.

How can I do it?

(Why does this javascript not work for other forms?)

```
function Check(frm)
{
    for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++){
        frm[i].checked = (document.form3.CheckAll.value == "Check All") ? 'checked' : '';
    }
    document.form3.CheckAll.value = (document.form3.CheckAll.value == "Check All") ? "Uncheck All" : 'Check All';
}
```

My other form is called:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<? echo $row['Report ID'] ?>"/>
</form>
```

And the javascript code is ran from this form/button:

```
<form name="form3" method="post" action="">
<input style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; border: 1px #000000 solid;" type="button" id="CheckAll" name="CheckAll" value="Check All" onClick="Check(document.myform)">
<input style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; border: 1px #000000 solid;" type="submit" id="DeleteCheck" name="DeleteCheck" value="Delete Checked"></center>
</form>
```

Why does it not work?

EDIT: I realised that the form: 'myform' is looped afew times, (As the code above works when it is not looped) So how can I make it work if myform IS looped?

Thanks alot,

Comment: The checked property should be `true` or `false` — don't depend on type coercion from strings with stuff in them an empty strings, that's just ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to get rid of the CheckAll member and instead base the new checkbox value on the current, something like:

```
function Check(frm)
{
    for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++){
        frm[i].checked = (frm[i].checked == '') ? 'checked' : '';
    }
}
```

This code has not been tested as I'm on my iPhone but you should get the essence of it.

Comment: Err. So the CheckAll button should set all the ones currently checked to unchecked and vice versa? Eugh. More toggle all than check all.

Comment: When I read "I have some javascript code which orginally checked/unchecked multiple checkboxes which was great." I understand that it's what's he's looking for, a toggle function... But I may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because the other form doesn't have a `CheckAll`, and it is that form you are looking for it on.

Comment: Grab the form explicitly. Pass the form as another argument. Make it an optional argument and switch back to the current form is not specified. Have a CheckAll for each form. There are lots of approaches.

Comment: And I do not know any of these approaches unfortunately, this is why I asked the question. :(

Comment: I listed three and a half of the other approaches in sentences before the one where I stated that there were lots. Pick one of them.

Comment: Well i've changed 'frm.CheckAll.value' to 'document.form2.CheckAll.value' So now the button changes text (Like it used too when it worked) But the checkboxes still do not change :(

Comment: Think I know the problem: I have a loop around the 'myform' so because there are two, its not working :( Any chance you know how to fix this? :)